# c# background worker in mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker

I am using treeview in my wpf application. Child elements must load in background thread.

What should I use for this task? Background worker? How should I rewrite it? My viewmodel is:

```
public class SpaceObjectViewModel : TreeViewItemViewModel
{
    private SpaceObject mSpaceObject;
    private BackgroundWorker mBackgroundWorker;  

    public SpaceObjectViewModel(SpaceObject spaceObject, SpaceObjectViewModel parentViewModel)
        : base(parentViewModel, true)
    {
        mSpaceObject = spaceObject;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return mSpaceObject.Name; }
    }

    protected override void LoadChildren()
    {
        foreach (SpaceObject space in DataManager.Instance.Read(mSpaceObject.ObjectId))
            base.Childrens.Add(new SpaceObjectViewModel(space, this));
    }
}
```

Comment: Bgw might work. Have you looked up how to use it? You need to register its events, merely.

Comment: You can use async and wait statements.

Comment: What kind of Base.Children is ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In .net 4.5 you can use async/await like this:

```
protected async override void LoadChildren()
{
    foreach (SpaceObject space in await Task.Run(() => DataManager.Instance.Read(mSpaceObject.ObjectId)))
        base.Childrens.Add(new SpaceObjectViewModel(space, this));
}
```

Because of the `await` you need `async` in your signature.

`Task.Run(() => ...)` Queues the specified work to run on the ThreadPool and returns a task or Task(TResult) handle for that work.